# Is it possible to add wrapped numbers without boxing/unboxing?

Tags: java, numbers, sum, wrapper

I'm getting a Long value as a result of some method. Now, when I want to add 1 to that number, the compiler warns me about the value being boxed / unboxed to perform the sum.

```
public Long getLongValue() {return new Long(5L);}
// ...
Long val = getLongValue();
val++; // Warning: The expression of type Long is unboxed into long
val = val + 1L; // Warning: The expression of type Long is unboxed into long
```

Since Long class doesn't seem to have an "add" method, is there any way to avoid this autoboxing behaviour?

(Note: I know I can just @suppressWarnings or manually box / unbox the values instead of using the Autoboxing feature. What I'm trying to achieve is to totally avoid boxing / unboxing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since, as you noted, `Long` does not have have any `add()` method (or any other arithmetic methods) you have no choice but to unbox (manually or automatically) it to do calculations with it and then box (manually or automatically) the result.

It will likely be more performant if you unbox before any calculations, do all the calculations, and rebox at the end rather than boxing and unboxing during each calculation (and sub-calculation).

Answer (score 0):

Do it this way

```
    long val = getLongValue();
    val++; 
    val = val + 1L;
```

it's more efficient and there will be no warnings